# Matplotlib: get figure title?

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

Suppose I have a figure already plotted and I have added a title with `f.suptitle('My favorite title')`. Is there anything that tells me what this title is? Something like `title = f.get_title()` such that `title` has now the string "My favorite title" stored in it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
f._suptitle
```

or via

```
f.texts
```